# UV unwrapping problem with image mapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I am doing this Blender Guru [tutorial on camera mapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9r9tKX5olY). In the first half hour he shows how you can map a 2D image on a cube. When doing this at about 31:00 minutes he encounters a problem. The floor and left wall are not fitting together. I have also that kind of an issue but I don't like the way he solves this. The problem is that the Project from View of this Left Wall does not fit with the image. How to solve that in the UV image editor ?

[image]

You can see that the image and the project view don't match. I don't really understand what is causing this problem and how to solve that

[image]

Comment: In my opinion the issue you have is that the camera perspective does not match that of the scene... seems like the original scene uses a wider lens.

Comment: yes ...I think so, but what is the solution ? Try to find the correct camera perspective or correct the image perspective in Photoshop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm .... There is a perspective problem (the perspective of the image and the Projected View don't match) and I think I should solve that problem in Photoshop. When I export the UV layout after UV unwrapping I can correct the perspective of the image in Photoshop (with the WARP tool) so that the image fits with the UV layout.

[image]

I think Cegaton is right with his comment (camera perspective in Blender and image perspective don't match) but correcting the perspective of the image in Photoshop does the job pretty good.

There seems to be a Blender Addon named [BLAM](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/23/blam-geometry-camera-matching-add-on/) that helps to solve this kind of challenges (thanks Cegaton).

Comment: you still have some of the floor's texture mapped on to the wall...