# why is my project from view distorted?

Tags: uv, shaders

Looks like a total beginner question and i apologize for being a shader beginner...

but i thought, if i do a project from view, i would get a non distorted result, but i didn't get it.

Why is that and how can i solve that?

[image]

i just took a simple cube, deleted one side face and expanded it in edit mode in x-direction.
Then i changed the view so that i can look inside and used "project from view" with this shader:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi,Chris, with no disrespect, I think we may call this a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/213542/35559, where @creativecoding gives a couple of excellent self-answers, including a method which does not require subdivision for better interpolation. The root of the problem is that [barycentric](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates.html) interpolation used in texture look-up is not the same as Cartesian interpolation in the view, so with few fixed data-points, the interpolations differ significantly.

Comment: .. But since @Gordon has given an accepted answer, we'll let it go ...

Comment: @RobinBetts I have to admit, it is a duplicate... didn't come across the other question back then. However, a couple of excellent self-answers is a bit exaggerated ;) One is the same as mine - adding more vertices. The other which does not require more subdivisions is probably not applicable here, since the texture coordinate _Window_ will not work in Chris' example, because the view he wants to project from is not looking through the camera.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  , Hehe... OK :D . I guess I was impressed because I'd never seen _any_  method to avoid subdivision, anywhere, and the second answer came across as an Aha! moment, for me. (Most workflows _would_ want to map through a matched camera)

Comment: @RobinBetts: i have no problem if you call this a duplicate! just do it as you think. I am only interested in solving problems ;)

Comment: @RobinBetts I agree, most would want that and I actually don't know of what use is having a non-distorted UV projection only in the viewport which will not look correct through the camera... but that's none of my business :)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann & Chris  .. Personally I see no problem leaving this Q&A up.. If nothing else, the title makes it easier to find. As Gordon says, the situation is a bit different , here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, since you have simple quads with only four vertices at each corner, Blender has a hard time to figure out how to distribute the image on those faces. The solution (not ideal to keep a low polycount, admittedly) to this is subdividing the mesh and then unwrap it again with *Project from View*:

[image: subdivided mesh]

And the result looks like this. I've set the *Scale* in the *Mapping* node back to 1 and scaled the UV map up so that the lion fills the mesh mostly. You have to experiment for yourself how many subdivisions are necessary to get an acceptable result:

[image: result]

There is an older tutorial by Default Cube where he explains this: [Realistic 3D? EASY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWkKV0HxwFQ)

Comment: thanks for that additional link and of course for the answer!

Comment: +1 but worth noting: @creative coding shows [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214200/35559) that you don't have to subdivide in the geometry to reduce the discrepancy between barycentric interpolation across triangles used by texture look-up, and the natural per-pixel interpolation in the view. Default Cube missed that one :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Right, but as mentioned in my comment above: the method without subdividing requires that you want to project the image on the UVs by looking through the camera, which is not the case in Chris' setup. Also it works probably best if the image you want to project onto the UVs has the same aspect ratio as the render size from the camera.